# python in azure website using webapp2

Tags: python, azure, webapp2

I would like to try to develop website using python, upload to azure website. I saw there is a tutorial using django. Is there a tutorial using webapp2?

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, Windows Azure Web Sites don't support Python.

Comment: No, azure websites supported python.

Comment: Looks like you're correct: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-sites-with-django/. Must have been announced this week.